# WPF Visibility Binding to Converted Instance Property

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, type-conversion

So I have a button. I want to set the visibility of the button according to the value of an integer property of a class. This requires a data binding and a converter.

The XAML code for the button is as follows:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <local:Button1VisibilityConverter x:Key="Button1VisibilityConverter"/>
        <local:ModeValues x:Key="ModeHolder"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="150" Margin="92,90,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="301">
            <Button Content="1" Height="58" Background="#FFA20000" Foreground="White" Visibility="{Binding Source={StaticResource ModeHolder}, Path=State, Converter=Button1VisibilityConverter}"/>
            <Button Content="2" Height="58" Background="#FF16A200" Foreground="White"/>
            <Button Content="3" Height="58" Background="#FF4200A2" Foreground="White"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

My converter is as follows:

```
class Button1VisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targettype, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            int mode = (int)value;
            if (mode == ModeValues.Red)
                return System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            else
                return System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The class that has the property I want to control the visibility is as follows:

```
public class ModeValues : IObservable<int>
    {
        private int _state = -1;

        public static int Red
        {
            get
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }

        public static int Green
        {
            get
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }

        public static int Purple
        {
            get
            {
                return 2;
            }
        }

        public int State
        {
            get
            {
                return this._state;
            }
            set
            {
                this.State = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

I have no idea why it isn't working. I thought I had to bind the visibility to the property of the instance of the ModeHolder, make the ModeHolder observable, and convert the int to a visibility. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Converter=Button1VisibilityConverter
```

should be:

```
Converter={StaticResource Button1VisibilityConverter}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have found out that the IObservable needs to be more fully implemented, but this fixed my issue.